# Arrow up / previous command in VSCode Python Interactive not working

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm working with VSCode on an Ubuntu 18.04 machine. Everything is fine except that I can't get back to the previous command in Python Interactive Window via Arrow Up. It works in the integrated terminal though, integrated shell is /bin/bash.

I have no idea where this is coming from. I changed "keyboard.dispatch" to "keyCode", but that's not the problem. I also tried different versions of the python-extension.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Did U solve this? I have this issue running git bash Windows 10.

Comment: In my case, up/down arrows did not work in python 3.7.4, they did in python 3.7.9.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful for you as an Ubuntu user, but I came across the same problem in Windows this week. In my case, the issue cropped up after I installed the Python extension in VS Code (or at least I didn't notice the issue before this). The combination of using the Python extension, Git Bash for terminal, and python virtual environment killed the up arrow feature for me. Using python outside a virtual environment works fine. My solution was to use Command Prompt as the terminal when I wanted to use a virtual environment interactively.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem but this is the only option I could find that worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling myself for a decent amount of time without a solution. As I'm currently on a new machine, I was reconfiguring the `vscodevim` extension as it interferes with several standard keybindings like `ctrl + b` for closing the side panel. The same seems to be true for the `UpArrow` and `DownArrow` keybindings.

Solution: I first changed the keybindings for `extension.vim_down` and `extension.vim_up` to `ctrl + down / up` and later removed them completely.

[image: changed vim keybindings to ctrl + down / up]

Now I can use the history in my interactive window again ✌

Answer (score -1):

In my situation, although I delete all the shortcuts of UpArrow, I still can get the previous command through UpArrow in Python interactive. This means there's no way to configure this shortcut, it was built in the plugin which built in Python extension.

So it's some problem with your Python extension, but you said you have tried to install a different version of Python extension but still not work. Make sure you have deleted it completely -> delete the extension folder manually(it's under C:\Users[UserName].vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-xxx).

Answer (score -1):

This might work out for you.

Go to Settings > WorkBench > Editor Management

Enable Prefer History Based Language Detection.